# hyperref CheckBox doesn't show up on any Windows pdf viewer

Tags: hyperref

I am trying to make a simple form using the hyperref package, however I am having issues using the form on any Windows OS pdf viewer.

The following is the CheckBox code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{Form}
        \CheckBox[checkboxsymbol=5, name=ch1, width=0.4cm, height=0.4cm]{Yes\hspace{0.25cm}} \hspace{4cm} \CheckBox[checkboxsymbol=5, name=ch2, width=0.4cm, height=0.4cm]{No\hspace{0.25cm}}
    \end{Form}
\end{center}
```

Which works perfectly fine on my linux machine, but on any Windows machine the check mark does not appear upon clicking (it is clickable however).

I'm not sure what I have missed here, whether it is simple or not.

Comment: the checkbox code is faulty. Sometimes this year there will be an improvement, but not directly. See also https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/153. Side remark: use only on Form environment in your document, not around every box. Actually only using once `\Form` at the begin should be enough.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Are there any workarounds currently to resolve this?